# Transferring android database file to a web application

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Is there a better way in which  android database from sd card of my android phone can be transferred to a web application using visual basic?

Answer (score 0):

This [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) can be of use.

You need to extract the schema for your database for your new. Bear in mind that SQL syntax for SQLite is different from MySQL... (I assumed you need to transfer your android db to MySQL web db)

Read this [tutorial](http://www.maxkpage.com/blog/free-sqlite-to-mysql-converter-super-easy/)